# Can't change TextMeshPro's alpha in canvas gruoup (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, unity-ui, textmeshpro

I've been trying to change the alpha value of an object and all of its children with a canvas group in Unity (I'm making UI animations), and every child will fade out, except for TextMeshPro objects. Why is that, and is there a way to make it work?

[image: image of the editor showing the alpha value at zero]

In this case, I've changed backgroundImage's Canvas Group alpha to zero, but as you can see al of its TextMeshPro children are still visible. I can't change their value individually, because some of them are instantiated at runtime.
I've also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72245314/how-to-fade-out-in-a-canvas-canvas-group-and-its-children-objects) but it didn't seem to work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using `TextMeshPro` script instead of `TextMeshProUGUI`. `CanvasGroup` will not work with `TextMeshPro` variant as it is supposed to be used in the 3d world space, not canvas.

Comment: It works, thanks. I didn't even know about the difference, I guess now I have to change all of the TextMeshPro objects since I use them only for the canvas.